# Name of the relationship between a child object and parent interface?

Tags: object-oriented, terminology

If `Pet` is a class that implements the interface `INameable`, and `dog` is an instance of `Pet`, what is the name of the relationship between `dog` and `INameable`?

In casual conversation and while talking with other devs, I would unthinkingly call `dog` an instance of `INameable`. This is always understood but might not be technically correct. An obviously technically-correct name I can come up with is "an instance of an implementation of" but that's verbose.

What's the shortest technically-correct name for the relationship between `dog` and `INameable`?

Perhaps `dog` is *also* simply an "implementation" of `INameable`, but then what's the difference between the type of implementation that `Pet` is and the type of implementation that `dog` is?

Comment: This question is like asking, "given the taxonomy of dogs, what relationship does my dog - fido - have to all mammals?". So, I think the best answer is, IS-A.

Answer (score 1):

> "I would ... call dog an instance of INameable"

That's fine, don't overthink it. Each instance of `Pet` is also an instance of `INameable`, that's the gist of inheritance. This kind of "replaceability" has also a name, it is called [Liskov substitions principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

> Perhaps dog is also simply an "implementation" of INameable

No, that wording would only fit for a class `Dog` which derives from `Pet`.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is asking about a single level hierarchy (`INameable > Pet`) & an instance of the derived class (`dog: Pet`). On a conceptual level, generally a dog *is* an instance of INameable - in the ordinary sense of "instance" (example, occurrence) - because of the "is-a" relationship between the types (`INameable` includes all `Pet` instances, and therefore the `dog`).

Comment: I don't think most people would have a problem with that, as OP has noted. In fact, in various languages, `dog instanceof INameable` will return `true`. The only context where this meaning may cause confusion is when talking about language and/or compiler design, where "instance" might be used with the meaning "an instantiation of a <concrete_type>" (so in this context, an interface cannot be instantiated). But I don't know if there's a name for the transitive relationship either. Maybe something like "an instance of an INameable derivative", but I'd only use that if the distinction matters.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: sorry, I must have been too tired last night, completely misread the question. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

There is no literature yet supporting this but **incarnation** seems fit. This sets it apart from implementation which refers to the design. The incarnation is the concrete, "physical" version, the build.